# Sanity check: how low can a p-value go?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, sample-size, statistical-power

I am using a ranksum test to compare the median of two samples ($n=120000$) and have found that they are significantly different with: `p = 1.12E-207`. Should I be suspicious of such a small $p$-value or should I attribute it to the high statistical power associated with having a very large sample? Is there any such thing as a suspiciously low $p$-value?

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78839.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

P-values on standard computers (using IEEE double precision floats) can get as low as [approximately $10^{-308}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985).  These can be legitimately correct calculations when effect sizes are large and/or standard errors are low.  Your value, if computed with a T or normal distribution, corresponds to an effect size of about 31 standard errors.  Remembering that standard errors usually scale with the reciprocal square root of $n$, that reflects a difference of less than 0.09 standard deviations (assuming all samples are independent).  In most applications, there would be nothing suspicious or unusual about such a difference.

Interpreting such p-values is another matter.  Viewing a number as small as $10^{-207}$ or even $10^{-10}$ as a probability is exceeding the bounds of reason, given all the ways in which reality is likely to deviate from the probability model that underpins this p-value calculation.  A good choice is to report the p-value as being less than the smallest threshold you feel the model can reasonably support: often between $0.01$ and $0.0001$.

Comment: When I reported ''$p<10^{-26}$'' in a conference paper, a reviewer told me that I should change it to ''$p<0.001$'' in order to follow APA guidelines.

Comment: @whuber - Beautifully stated.

Comment: (+1) At some point it's more likely that the government is nefariously flipping bits in your RAM remotely with super spy technology...

Comment: (+1) You can actually get down to just below $5 \times 10^{-324}$ in IEEE double precision floating point. But, your numerical routines for calculating $p$-values are almost guaranteed to fall apart before then. Unless you know for a fact that your modeling assumptions are perfectly correct (and when are they?), a $p$-value eventually just becomes a measure of the sample size once the sample gets large enough.

Comment: @Cardinal we're both wrong about the limits: apart from denormalized values, the [smallest IEEE double](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) is approximately $10^{-308}$, corresponding to ten bits for a base-2 exponent.

Comment: @whuber: I was listing the smallest positive representable number, including subnormal values: $2^{-1074}$. :)

Comment: @ThomasLevine: isn't that just losing information? Not much information, to be sure, but it's also not saving any space, or making it easier to read. Sounds like a pointless convention...

Comment: I agree with @naught: especially for those trying to reproduce or check a paper, having a reasonably precise value for comparison is helpful.  Changing "$\lt 10^{-26}$" to "$\lt 0.001$" erases 23 significant digits!  Evidently, the APA guidelines focus on reporting results rather than on checking them -- to the detriment of all science.

Comment: There are many assumptions required for the correctness of extremely low p-values, not the least of which are the correctness of the chosen data model and how the actual experimental design used fits in with the p-value calculations.

Comment: @Frank I suspect you might be confounding *correctness* with *interpretation.*  All p-values are computed from hypothetical models, usually *expected* to be counter-factual.

Comment: You're right, but the fact that the models are not exactly right means that for the purpose at hand it is pretty silly to compute p-values to such small values.

Comment: @Frank Usually, yes; but not always.  The precision can be useful for readers who wish to make Bonferroni or other corrections, as well as readers attempting to reproduce the results.  Re "pretty silly:" I have seen more than one expert report produced in litigation that not only gleefully quoted astronomically small p-values (a striking one was around $10^{-80},$ quoted for a Fisher Exact Test by an Ivy League sociologist), they made a point of writing out all the zeros in decimal notation.  It impressed the judge. :-(

Answer (score 18):

There is nothing suspicious -- extremely low p-values like yours are pretty common when sample sizes are large (as yours is for comparing medians). As whuber mentioned, normally such p-values are reported as being less than some threshold (e.g. <0.001).

One thing to be careful about is that p-values only tells you whether the difference in median is is *statistically* significant. Whether the difference is significant enough in magnitude is something you will have to decide: e.g. for large sample sets, extremely small differences in means/medians can be statistically significant, but it might not mean very much.

Answer (score 5):

A p-value can achieve a value of 0.

Suppose I am testing the composite hypothesis about the value of a range of a uniform 0, $\theta$ random variable. If I set $\mathcal{H}_0: \theta = 1$ and sample a value of $X=1.1$, you see it's impossible to observe such a value or higher under the null hypothesis. The p-value is 0.