# p-value reported as 3.2531E-129 in excel does not work in CHIINV function

Tags: chi-squared-test, excel

When I insert the p-value `3.2531E-129` into excel's `CHIINV` function I get `#NOMBRE` as a result.
How do I find or report the chi-square value if this doesn't work?
Someone suggested I wrote out the 0 when the value was `6.1203E-05` to `0,0000061203`.
So, how can I change `3.2531E-129`  to `0.000000......32531`?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to input the degrees of freedom as well:

Comment: Try to use this website. http://web2.0calc.com/ it solves my problem too! :). Now it shows clearly why it is written as E at the end of the number.

Answer (score 3):

You need to input degrees of freedom as well. I tried
=CHISQ.INV.RT(3.253E-139,2) and got 637.76

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.  My degrees of freedom is 1.  I tried it again and got the same error message.  So opened a new sheet and did the entire calculation again and it doesn't even give me an E response for the P value.  Could my work sheet have got corrupt somehow?

Comment: My question still remains about the E value at the end.  What to do when an p-value e.g. comes out as 1.28441E-12.  Do I write out all of the zeros?

Comment: @alis Maybe you should look at http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11812.

Comment: You do not need to write out the zeros. But the result from the inverse chisquare distribution with that probability is either too big or too small for Excel to write, depending on whether you use chisq.inv (left tail) or chisq.inv.rt (right tail)

Comment: Thank you so much this answers many of my questions about reporting results!