# How should tiny $p$-values be reported? (and why does R put a minimum on 2.22e-16?)

Tags: r, p-value, reporting, precision

For some tests in `R`, there is a lower limit on the [p-value](/questions/tagged/p-value) calculations of $2.22 \cdot 10^{-16}$. I'm not sure why it's this number, if there is a good reason for it or if it's just arbitrary. A lot of other stats packages just go to `0.0001`, so this is a much higher level of precision. But I haven't seen too many papers reporting $p < 2.22\cdot 10^{-16}$ or $p = 2.22\cdot 10^{-16}$.

Is it a common/best practice to report this computed value or is it more typical to report something else (like `p < 0.000000000000001`)?

Comment: If you get such small p-value and want to calculate the actual p-value, you can use this function in excel =TDIST(t, df, 2) Add the values of your 't' and df and you will get the actual p-value.

Comment: @user133545 is there *any* reason why Excel would return more precise estimate then R..? As far as I know, it is much *less* precise.

Comment: `...But I haven't seen too many papers reporting p<2.22⋅10−16....` See some [GWAS papers](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/gwas/docs/file-downloads), there are many papers showing results for pvalues in hundreds, e.g.: Prostate cancer KLK region, p = 9x10^-186.

Comment: See also whuber's answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11812.

Comment: There is no lower limit on the calculation. There's a lower limit on what is **printed by default**, but the p-value is calculated to much higher precision than this in most cases.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

There's a good reason for it.

The value can be found via `noquote(unlist(format(.Machine)))`

```
           double.eps        double.neg.eps           double.xmin 
         2.220446e-16          1.110223e-16         2.225074e-308 
          double.xmax           double.base         double.digits 
        1.797693e+308                     2                    53 
      double.rounding          double.guard     double.ulp.digits 
                    5                     0                   -52 
double.neg.ulp.digits       double.exponent        double.min.exp 
                  -53                    11                 -1022 
       double.max.exp           integer.max           sizeof.long 
                 1024            2147483647                     4 
      sizeof.longlong     sizeof.longdouble        sizeof.pointer 
                    8                    12                     4
```

If you look at the help, (`?".Machine"`):

```
double.eps  

the smallest positive floating-point number x such that 1 + x != 1. It equals 
double.base ^ ulp.digits if either double.base is 2 or double.rounding is 0; 
otherwise, it is (double.base ^ double.ulp.digits) / 2. Normally 2.220446e-16.
```

Very loosely, it's essentially a value below which you can be quite confident the value will be pretty *numerically* meaningless - in that any smaller value isn't likely to be an accurate calculation of the value we were attempting to compute. (Having studied a little numerical analysis, depending on what computations were performed by the specific procedure, there's a good chance numerical meaninglessness comes in a fair way above that.)

But *statistical* meaning will have been lost far earlier. Note that p-values depend on assumptions, and the further out into the extreme tail you go the more heavily the true p-value (rather than the nominal value we calculate) will be affected by the mistaken assumptions, in some cases even when they're only a little bit wrong. Since the assumptions are simply not going to be all exactly satisfied, middling p-values may be reasonably accurate (in terms of relative accuracy, perhaps only out by a modest fraction), but extremely tiny p-values may be out by many orders of magnitude.

Which is to say that usual practice  (something like the "<0.0001" that you say is common in packages, or the APA rule that Jaap mentions in his answer) is probably not so far from sensible practice, but the approximate point at which things lose meaning beyond saying '*it's very very small*' will of course vary quite a lot depending on circumstances.

This is one reason why I can't suggest a general rule - there can't be a single rule that's even remotely suitable for everyone in all circumstances - change the circumstances a little and the broad grey line marking the change from somewhat meaningful to relatively meaningless will change, sometimes by a long way.

If you were to specify sufficient information about the exact circumstances (e.g. it's a regression, with *this* much nonlinearity, *that* amount of variation in this independent variable, *this* kind and amount of dependence in the error term, *that* kind of and amount of heteroskedasticity, *this* shape of error distribution), I could simulate 'true' p-values for you to compare with the nominal p-values, so you could see when they were too different for the nominal value to carry any meaning.

But that leads us to the second reason why - even if you specified enough information to simulate the true p-values - I still couldn't responsibly state a cut-off for even those circumstances.

What you report depends on people's preferences - yours, and your audience. Imagine you told me enough about the circumstances for me to decide that I wanted to draw the line at a nominal $p$ of $10^{-6}$.

All well and good, we might think - except your own preference function (what looks right to you, were you to look at the difference between nominal p-values given by stats packages and the the ones resulting from simulation when you suppose a particular set of failures of assumptions) might put it at $10^{-5}$ and the editors of the journal you want to submit to might put have their blanket rule to cut off at $10^{-4}$, while the next journal might put it at $10^{-3}$ and the next may have no general rule and the specific editor you got might accept even lower values than I gave ... but one of the referees may then have a specific cut off!

In the absence of knowledge of their preference functions and rules, and the absence of knowledge of your own utilities, how do I responsibly suggest any general choice of what actions to take?

I can at least tell you the sorts of things that I do (and I don't suggest this is a good choice for you at all):

There are few circumstances (outside of simulating p-values) in which I would make much of a p less than $10^{-6}$ (I may or may not mention the value reported by the package, but I wouldn't make anything of it other than it was very small, I would usually emphasize the meaningless of the exact number). Sometimes I take a value somewhere in the region of $10^{-5}$ to $10^{-4}$ and say that p was much less than that. On occasion I do actually do as suggested above - perform some simulations to see how sensitive the p-value is in the far tail to various violations of the assumptions, particularly if there's a specific kind of violation I am worried about.

That's certainly helpful in informing a choice - but I am as likely to discuss the results of the simulation as to use them to choose a cut-off-value, giving others a chance to choose their own.

An alternative to simulation is to look at some procedures that are more robust* to the various potential failures of assumption and see how much difference to the p-value that might make. Their p-values will also not be particularly meaningful, but they do at least give some sense of how much impact there might be. If some are very different from the nominal one, it also gives more of an idea *which* violations of assumptions to investigate the impact of. Even if you don't report any of those alternatives, it gives a better picture of how meaningful your small p-value is.

* Note that here we don't really need procedures that are robust to gross violations of some assumption; ones that are less affected by relatively mild deviations of the relevant assumption should be fine for this exercise.

I will say that when/if you do come to do such simulations, even with quite mild violations, in some cases it can be surprising at how far even not-that-small p-values can be wrong. That has done more to change the way I personally interpret a p-value than it has shifted the specific cut-offs I might use.

When submitting the results of an actual hypothesis test to a journal, I try to find out if they have any rule. If they don't, I tend to please myself, and then wait for the referees to complain.

Comment: I especially like the comment on *statistical meaning* being lost far earlier.

Comment: Great answer! I appreciate all the detail on this, it clears up why R gives this number. But it doesn't really answer the question of what to report.

Comment: I rather felt I had addressed the issue, in the sense that I explained why it wasn't responsible to make a specific suggestion. Note that I do discuss why it makes sense to report something like the "<0.0001" that's common practice in some packages. There's a couple of reasons why I don't suggest a specific number - the first of which I gave. I will expand on that reason and the second one in an edit.

Comment: paul, I have added some more substantial discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the additions. I agree that you had said why it wasn't responsible to make a specific suggestion, but I still needed to do a specific thing, i.e. report something :) This is a very thorough explanation so I'm giving you the points. Although simply doing what a style guide suggests is a good answer too, maybe with a footnote saying that it's probably much much smaller, as you suggest.

Comment: Yes, you do need to do something; the point of my more extensive commentary was to convey that I can't tell you what you should choose to do, I can only discuss the issues that come into your choice. I hope I have done so, but I am happy to try to clarify any issues further if I can.

Comment: I think there may be a point to writing $p\ll0.0001$ when that makes sense.

Answer (score 30):

What common practice is might depend on your field of research. The manual of the American Psychological Association (APA), which is one of the most often used citation styles, states (p. 139, 6th edition):

> Do not use any value smaller than *p < 0.001*

Comment: Although this is what I also usually cite (+1), I am not sure whether or not one needs to revise this recommendation by one decimal place, given the recent recommendation of Valen Johnson in [PNAS](http://www.pnas.org/content/110/48/19313.short): "Make 0.005 the default level of significance [...]. Associate highly significant test results with P values that are less than 0.001."

Comment: Good answer. There's no style guides and no real standards in my fields, at least not for p-values. I do interdisciplinary work but I guess computer science and HCI would be the field for this. I think APA style would be where authors would turn, since the methods are generally borrowed from cognitive psych or other areas that the APA would cover.

Comment: Particle physics uses a [$5\sigma$ rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Particle_physics) (you might have seen it in the news with the confirmation of the Higgs boson), which blows way past this limit (being smaller even than $p < 10^{-6}$). Standards differ by area!

Comment: @Glen_b: Good point about $5\sigma$ in particle physics, but I guess what you wrote in your answer about sensitivity to assumptions etc. explains (or is at least part of the reason) why they report sigmas (i.e. basically $z$-statistic) instead of $p$-values. Once the $p$-value is below $0.0001$ or something (my usual advice is to report as many zeroes as one feels comfortable to print without switching to exponential notation), it's probably more meaningful to look at $z$-value than at $p$-value.

Comment: @amoeba Yeah, I think you're right.

Comment: This is an awful recommendation. Any serious research field should be able to prove their hypothesis with p-values way under 0.001. This may be saying more about psichology than about p-values

Answer (score 16):

Such extreme p-values occur more often in fields with very large amounts of data, such as genomics and process monitoring. In those cases, it's sometimes reported as -log<sub>10</sub>(p-value). See for example, [this figure from Nature](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v478/n7367/fig_tab/nature10405_F1.html), where the p-values go down to 1e-26.

-log<sub>10</sub>(p-value) is [called "LogWorth"](http://blogs.sas.com/content/jmp/2013/10/01/violating-the-anna-karenina-principle-logworth-scaling/) by statisticians I work with at JMP.

Comment: This is true, and worth pointing out, but it may also be worth mentioning that in this case the $p$-value should be really thought of **only** as an index of signal strength -- such small $p$-values (sometimes even if corrected for multiple comparisons) are so tiny that the probability that the NSA broke in and tampered with your data (and then brainwashed you so you can't remember) is far, far, higher than the nominal $p$-value.

Comment: This is pretty vague - what are "very large amounts of data" and what are "fields with very large amounts of data"? Depending on your definition, big datasets can be found in just about every field that has data. And I found tons of these values in work I was doing and I would not consider the datasets particularly big.

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness, @paul. The specific fact I wanted to add was that in genomics in particular such large data/tiny p-values is common enough that you see -log(p) reported instead, and the p-value is sometimes beyond 1e-16. The vagueness follows the adage that "with enough data all statistics are significant" (having small p-values).

Comment: Oh, I didn't get that you were talking about the large sample size problem and it's inflationary effect on significance. But it's interesting that such small values are reported in Nature given what @Glen_b is saying about the difficulty in interpreting the meaning of such small values in his answer

Comment: @paul With large data test power doesn't matter. The tiniest non-zero relationship, perhaps due to sampling bias or something, would give you p-values indistiguishable from zero as long as the dataset is big enough.

Comment: @Jase ok thanks. You might want to explain this in a separate answer in more detail, if you're saying something beyond what was said in this answer and comments

Comment: @BenBolker Indeed, while less probable than "the NSA tampered with your data", even events like "A cosmic ray flipped several important bits in your data" are far, far more likely than those probabilities.

Comment: In a [2015 neuroscience paper](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/vaop/ncurrent/full/nature14273.html) published in Nature, authors report $p<10^{-100}$ a couple of times when presenting correlation coefficients ($\rho\approx0.9$ and $n\sim 500$). Made me smile and remember your comments here, @Ben and Glen_b.

Comment: Here is a new finding in my quest for the minimal p-value reported in the literature: [another 2015 neuroscience paper](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v518/n7538/abs/nature14151.html) published in Nature (from a group that has just got 2014 Nobel prize, by the way) reports $p=2.2\times 10^{-226}$. Wow. (The paper is actually still great.) Cc to @Glen_b.

Comment: @amoeba I wonder if the algorithms for calculating normal CDF for tha tails around p=1e-100 are precise enough to calculate it... I guess extreme value theory would be more appropriate in here :)

Comment: @Tim I've just found another leader!!! [This 2015 neuroscience paper](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/35/27/10005) published in the Journal of Neuroscience (very reputable journal in the field) contains $p=1\times 10^{-286}$ and $p = 2\times 10^{-308}$. This last equation should probably have been reported as $p < 2\times 10^{-308}$ because that is the smallest possible double-precision float number, and the same paper contains it once more as inequality; so I assume it was a typo. Still, even disregarding `-308` for this reason, `-286` is a winner.

Comment: @amoeba Over in the Slate Star Codex comment section, [Daniel Wells notes](https://slatestarcodex.com/2019/05/07/5-httlpr-a-pointed-review/#comment-750750) that https://science.sciencemag.org/content/363/6425/eaau1043 reports a p-value of 3.6e-2382 ("not a typo, two *thousand*", says Daniel), which beats yours by quite a margin!

Comment: @MarkAmery Oh wow, thanks. I do suspect it's a typo though :-) I mean, I checked and that's what is written in the paper, but I think it's a typo in the paper. I think I will email the authors to double-check; will report back.

Comment: @MarkAmery I emailed the first author and he already replied: the p-value as reported is correct. He wrote that the chi-square statistic was converted into a p-value via `pchisq(..., log.p=TRUE)` and then the outcome was exponentiated.

Comment: @amoeba: I think you forgot the quotes around "correct" in [your last comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78839/how-should-tiny-p-values-be-reported-and-why-does-r-put-a-minimum-on-2-22e-1#comment764445_83060).

Comment: Getting back to this: I am actually not sure how they could have obtained e-2382 in R as the smallest value representable in R is e-308. I wouldn't know how to get e-2382 even using `log.p=TRUE` in `pchisq`. It should just output 0. Any ideas? @MarkAmery

Comment: Update to my previous comment: Well, actually it could be computed manually via logP/log(10).

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised no one mentioned this term explicitly, but @Glen_b alluded to it. The formal terminology for this issue is "machine epsilon." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon

For 64 bit double precision, the smallest representable value is $1.11e^{-16}$ or $2.22e^{-16}$ depending on how the software computes machine epsilon.