# Understanding the significance of very small p-values

Tags: p-value

I have calculated p-values of two independent groups (each group contains 17 samples and each sample is 100 points). I used scipy's [mann whitney u test](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.html). Further, I combined the p-values using [Fisher's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher's_method) as suggested by one of my colleagues. However, the p-values are just too small to make any sense to me. Here is a sample output:

```
import scipy.stats as stats
p_value_list = [3.3629559156133476e-56, 1.966307600030748e-254, 6.3484089727582271e-103, 
                3.1221165197874102e-92, 5.8797795864262639e-128, 4.0807369798923832e-130, 
                1.205918004734663e-187, 8.9953478731039129e-19, 2.1492251770664035e-127, 
                0.11623743456915718, 6.182421882338173e-13, 3.7920992534448722e-112, 3.5888837913096105e-97, 
                7.5565994692959197e-134, 0.0026669650138866794, 4.0844220972198632e-16, 4.583685848455044e-95]
results= stats.combine_pvalues(p_value_list)
print (results)
```

Which gives the following output (p is zero!)

```
(7172.864625387464, 0.0)
```

Now, my questions are:

- What is the meaning of small p-values (something like 1.2e-187)?
- How to interpret a p-value that is zero?
- Since I am writing a paper based on this calculation, how can one report this in a peer-reviewed journal?

Comment: With P-values that small you should be able to discern the difference as bloody obvious even without any statistical procedure. Is that a fair description of your results? If not, then you have done something wrong in the calculation.

Comment: Your combined P-value is calculated assuming the 17 P-values are all tests of the same null hypothesis. Is that really the case? You need to give a lot more detail about your data before a clear answer to your questions is possible.

Comment: See this: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78839

Answer (score 2):

1. A P-value of $10^{-187}$ is very strong evidence that the null hypothesis is not true, or that the statistical model used is inappropriate. Very strong indeed.
2. A P-value of zero occurs when the report runs out of decimal places. A P-value of $10^{-187}$ is not really different from a P-value of zero for most purposes.
3. Present the data and a measure of the effect size in addition to the P-values.

Comment: +1. A good existing thread is http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78839