# Is a p-value of < 2.2e-16 in r the same as a p-value that is asymptotically 0?

Tags: r, p-value, asymptotics

I am getting a p-value of  < 2.2e-16 for my coefficient in R, but I was wondering if I can say in my write up that it is asymptotically zero? Do these have the same meaning? What would I need to say the later?

Comment: Closely related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78839/how-should-tiny-p-values-be-reported-and-why-does-r-put-a-minimum-on-2-22e-1

Comment: This is just the limit r put on p-values in your output and is different from "asymptotically zero".

Answer (score 0):

To turn off scientific notation "e-notation" in R type the following function before running your analysis: options(scipen=999)