# about a p-value < 2.2e-16

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, descriptive-statistics, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, reporting

Although the question has been asked before, I hope that you do not mind if I am asking it again in our specific circumstances / context.

I would appreciate having your advice on the following:

in R, the `wilcox.test()` provides **"a p-value < 2.2e-16"**, when we compare sets of 1,000 genes expression (in the genomics field).

However, the journal asks us to provide the exact $p$-value.

Would it be legitimate to write : **"p-value = 0"** ?

Comment: I understand the journal want the exact p-value but I suspect you have access to the exact test statistic? They might be willing to accept the test statistic with the statement $ p < 2.2 \times 10^{-16}$

Comment: Not related to the question, but the journal is wrong and there is no sense in providing the p-value (what can one do with the information that the p-value was actually 2.1e-16, not 2.2e-16?).

Comment: Have you tried stating p<2.2e-16? This is about as exact as it gets. Surely it's more exact than something like 0.224, which the journal would probably happily accept. If they're not happy with p<2.2e-16, they basically demonstrate that they're clueless and should be boycotted... ;-)

Comment: p < 2.2e-16 may not be exact, but it's much more accurate that p = 0

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer is to ask the journal how to proceed.

Regarding the statistics, you don’t what the exact p-value is. Remember that the p-value is some kind of integral of a density. When you get out that far in the tail of a density, the numerical methods break down, and the value gets sensitive to violations of test assumptions. Is is $10^{-16}$ or $10^{-17}$ or $10^{-14}?$ Who knows!? But it also does not matter. The number you’re getting is R’s way of telling you that the answer is basically zero.

Answer (score 3):

You would hope the editors are sensible people and they are not going to insist on the exact p-value for something in the region of 1e-16. I would just report p < 2.2e-16 in the manuscript with a note to the editor saying that you cannot be more precise than that and it probably you don't need to.

I would much prefer that than reporting 'p = 0' since that is not really meaningful and it can be misleading since it's not clear how close you were to zero.

After all, what does it even mean *exact value*? How many decimal places? What it is the exact value of $\pi$? As far as your computing facilities go, your exact p-value *is* 'p < 1e-16' because you cannot do better than that.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the exact p-value no problem in R!
Here is a reproducible example showing what I mean (the data comes from the documentation, see `?wilcox.test`):

```
x <- c(1.83,  0.50,  1.62,  2.48, 1.68, 1.88, 1.55, 3.06, 1.30)
y <- c(0.878, 0.647, 0.598, 2.05, 1.06, 1.29, 1.06, 3.14, 1.29)
result=wilcox.test(x, y, paired = TRUE, alternative = "greater")

print(result)
# It prints p-value = 0.02

print(result$p.value)
# [1] 0.0195
```

You'll get some rounded form of the p-value if you `print(result)` because it looks better formatted that way, but you can access the exact value as shown in the snippet.

PS: The p-value cannot be exactly equal to 0 in this case. At best it will be numerically equal to 0 if the number is too small for the software to handle (see the link below).  I would report the exact p-value as asked by the journal (even it's not the most sensible thing, so long it makes them happy) ; and if it shows 0 I would at least write numerically equal to 0.

Relevant with a great answer: [How should tiny $p$-values be reported? (and why does R put a minimum on 2.22e-16?)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78839/how-should-tiny-p-values-be-reported-and-why-does-r-put-a-minimum-on-2-22e-1?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: @mdewey With all respect, I think Dave's answer is more to the point.  In many cases the p-value cannot be computed with accuracy greater than c. $10^{-12}$ (if one is lucky). Insisting on reporting any value less than that amounts to misunderstanding how statistical computations work. Thus, when I see people report p-values like "$0.0000\cdots00017$" (sometimes with *hundreds* of zeros written!), two red flags go up: one concerning ignorance of the calculation and another concerning an undue emphasis on the "astronomically small" size of the p-value.

Comment: The OP is asking about the exact situation where R *does not* return an exact number. The question is "how to proceed when X occurs", but this answer is basically "what to do in cases other than X". I don't really know what the phrase "numerically equal to zero" is supposed to mean, either. A p-value can only be zero if the hypothesis is literally impossible. If you have a meterstick marked in centimeters and want to measure something less than 1cm, you don't say the length is "numerically equal to zero" just because it's below your measurement limits.

Comment: @whuber the core problem is that the print method for objects of class htest prints the results in a neat format but the underlying stored result is also available. Ridiculously precise miniscule p-values are the norm in the field in which the OP works.

Comment: @mdewey Good point; understood.  But then it seems Glen_b has given a thorough answer in [the duplicate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78839).

Comment: I agree with above discussion. My answer was trying to give OP what he wanted (i.e. the "exact" p-value the journal asked for) although I agree it's not very sensible. That is why I linked Glen_b's answer calling for caution. With "numerically equal to 0", I meant to say that R can show a 0 p-value when you pull it out of the result object, but that's just because it's too small; i.e.  R's meterstick isn't precise enough to go along with your analogy

Comment: Dear all, many thanks for your comments and insights !