# can p-value be so much small like 9E-10

Tags: p-value

I'm new in statistics , and right now I'm trying to do an hypothesis testing , so to know which hypothesis is accepted (H0 or H1) , I used to see or study p-value between (0.01-0.99) , but when I tried to do the test right now I got p-value = 5.84e-10 (by using shapiro.test() in R), while the significant level is just 0.05 , is this p-value right ? or there is something wrong ?
thanks for reading

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78839 might be helpful.

Comment: P values can be any value between 0 and 1. In practice a lot of p values are extremely small; null hypotheses are very often false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine you are trying to test for normality, so as the p-value is less than 0.05 the null hypothesis is rejected and there is evidence that the data tested are not normally distributed, so you can do a qq-plot to confirm your result, dont try to interpret p-values they are just used as rejection points.

Heres some info on qq-plot
[https://data.library.virginia.edu/understanding-q-q-plots/#:~:text=In%20R%2C%20there%20are%20two,set%20that%20comes%20with%20R](https://data.library.virginia.edu/understanding-q-q-plots/#:%7E:text=In%20R%2C%20there%20are%20two,set%20that%20comes%20with%20R).

Comment: thank you for the answer